# Contar valores não nulos entre determinadas colunas de dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, ciência-de-dados

Possuo um dataframe com colunas de janeiro a setembro. Em cada uma dessas colunas existem linhas com valores numéricos, algumas são nulas.

O que preciso fazer é adicionar uma coluna total nesse dataframe com a quantidade de valores não nulos de cada linha. E que eu pudesse escolher e parametrizar, exemplo: quantidade de linhas com valores não nulos entre fevereiro e maio.

Conseguem me auxiliar?

Sds,

Answer (score 0):

Para criar uma coluna no seu DF com o número de dados não nulos em casa linha, você precisará das funções `notnull()` e `sum(1)`.

```
df['valores_nao_nulos'] = df.notnull().sum(1)
```

Para verificar se a linha inteira não possui dados nulos, você precisará das funções `isnull()` e `any(1)`

```
df['linha_possui_nulo?'] = df.isnull().any(1)
```

Se você achar necessário posso colocar os links da documentação das funções usadas aqui